# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta desde Oracle a MS SQL por medio de DB_Link?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta realizada desde SQL Developer 'Oracle' hacia MS SQL a travez de DB_Link (El DB_Link conecta atravez de ODBC configurado en mi Oracle Server), la cual funciona bien.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1@bdd1 s;
```

Pero cuando intento utilizar un `WHERE` a la columna `ACTVO=1` me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ORA-00904: "S"."ACTIVO": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Talvez alguien podria guiarme. Gracias de antmano por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 3):

Para quien le sirva esta información, he encontrado la respuesta. Se debe usar Doble Comilla en cada campo.

```
SELECT "Código", "Nombre", "Estado"
  FROM tabla@bdd1 s
 WHERE s."Estado"= 'Activo';
```

Comment: Datazo. Recuerda marcarla en un rato como aceptada!